# Reorder a vector element to be second in R

Tags: r, string, function, vector

Suppose we have some two-element string vectors like `A, B, C, ...` below. We only know one of the elements which is saved as object `second`.

Is there a way to make the `second` to be always the second element in `A, B, C, ...`?

```
A = c("time","prof") # --> must become `c("prof", "time")`

B = c("prof", "time") # --> remains Unchanged

C = c("time","ziba") # --> must become `c("ziba", "time")`

second = "time"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a helper function to move a particular value to the end of a vector

```
move_last <- function(x, v) {
  c(setdiff(x, v), intersect(x,v))
}
```

This works with the given vectors

```
move_last(A, second)
# [1] "prof" "time"
move_last(B, second)
# [1] "prof" "time"
move_last(C, second)
# [1] "ziba" "time"
move_last(c("apple", "banana"), second)
# [1] "apple"  "banana"
```

Answer (score 3):

If you know they are all length-two, then simply `c(x[!x %in% second], second)` will do, e.g.

```r
c(A[!A %in% second], second)
#> [1] "prof" "time"

c(B[!B %in% second], second)
#> [1] "prof" "time"

c(C[!C %in% second], second)
#> [1] "ziba" "time"
```

This would be equivalent to MrFlick's `move_last` function:

```r
move_last <- function(x, y) c(x[!x %in% y], y)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try `==` + `order`, e.g.,

```
f <- function(x, y = second) x[order(x == y)]
```

and you will see

```
> f(A)
[1] "prof" "time"

> f(B)
[1] "prof" "time"

> f(C)
[1] "ziba" "time"
```